Can't get bluetooth permissions in react native
I'm trying to get permissions to use bluetooth in Android, I've tried different options, both single and multiple requests, but I don't get permission requests. Moreover, requests for camera or other permissions appear
Code:
const requestPermissions = async () => {
  try {
    const bluetoothPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH,
      {
        title: 'Bluetooth Permission',
        message: 'This app needs Bluetooth access to scan for devices.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      }
    );

    const bluetoothAdminPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
      {
        title: 'Bluetooth Admin Permission',
        message: 'This app needs Bluetooth Admin access to manage Bluetooth settings.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      }
    );

    const locationPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location Permission',
        message: 'This app needs location access to scan for Bluetooth devices.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      }
    );

    if (
      bluetoothPermission !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED ||
      bluetoothAdminPermission !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED ||
      locationPermission !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
    ) {
      Alert.alert('Bluetooth permissions not granted');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error requesting permissions:', err);
  }
};

Also I tried this:
      const result = await requestMultiple([



Could you please provide the full code? I need to confirm the method you call.

Probably the react-native-permissions library can handle it better. I never used the build-in  permissions.
Anyway. Did you put the permissions also in the manifest file? Is your device supporting bluetooth?
Please also note that Android can be very annoying with permissions, there are many that are no longer supported or requires you to put a min or max supported sdk. Android Docs
